# In Powershell: ToLower() works, in VSC/Powershell not?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have win10 Pro and Powershell 5.1
On the other hand VSC(1.54.1) with the powershell extention (ms-vscode-powershell, v2021.2.2).

The command

```
 $day = $day.ToLower()
```

on the Powershell prompt works fine

But in VSC it says:

```
+ $dayName = $dayName.ToLower()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

MethodNotFound???

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What's in `$day` and what is in `$dayName`? What did you do to store values in both variables?

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's a good question: in $day "Monday" and in $dayName is  (get-date).DayOfWeek that's "Tuesday"...

Comment: `$dayName.ToString().ToLower()` should solve your problem. `ToLower` is a string method and you are trying to use it on `System.DayOfWeek`, which doesn't have that method.

In order to keep track of your variables and just what they are, running `$myVariable.GetType().FullName` can be very handy - I use it all the time.

Comment: OK! That's it! But how can it be that "Tuesday" wasn't a string? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dayName.ToString().ToLower()` should do what you expect here (according to your comment).

`.ToLower()` is a string method and you are trying to use it on `System.DayOfWeek`, which doesn't have that method.

In order to keep track of your variables and just what they are, running $myVariable.GetType().FullName can be very handy - I use it all the time.

In your example, running

```
$day.GetType().FullName
$dayName.GetType().FullName
```

would probably result in something like

```
PS C:\> $day.GetType().FullName
System.String
PS C:\> $dayName.GetType().FullName
System.DayOfWeek
```

Comment: `"$dayName".ToLower()` will also work - `"`-quoted strings expand simple variable references automatically :-)

Comment: powershell is c# with helping wheels

Comment: Thanks Guys! The hint with "$dayName".ToLower() is also good to know! :). Also interesting that PS has to do with C#, which I don't know at all...!